# Upload file via dropzone without FormData

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I am using DropZone js (in jQuery code) to upload a file to server. The server takes only binary data in body and not a form data.

[image]

Is there anyway we can say DropZone to send binary data without wrapping it in FormData.
Or is there any way in jQuery to intercept the post call and strip the FormData and replace just the binary to body.